# Javascript Google Analytics authentication problems

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to track Google Analytics data in my Dashboard but I want a server-side authentication not a client side.

I found [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/authSample.html) login and tried to track my Data but it does not work really well...
Usually I used something like this:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    clientId: 'XXXXXX',
    container: 'auth-button'
});
var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector-container'
});
viewSelector.execute();

var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
query: {
  metrics: 'ga:sessions',
  dimensions: 'ga:date',
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday'
},
chart: {
  container: 'chart-container',
  type: 'LINE',
  options: {
    width: '100%'
     }
   }
});
```

Now my question is: how is it possible to mix those two scripts?
How can I get access to google analytics data with server side authentication?

Thank you very much

Comment: Check out the embedded API, I have heard of people feeding it an access token gotten from a server sided script.

Comment: yeah thats my plan but I have no idea where to get it from... I spend hours at all those pages https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#auth-example where can I obtain `access_token: 'XXXXXX'`

Comment: your going to have to get that from some server sided script using either a service account or Oauth2 to authenticate.   access tokens expire after an hour so your going to have to be feeding it a new one when it expires.

Comment: Is it this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent ? Sry I'm totally lost there are just too much possibilities and links and files and its the first time I'm working with google analytics. Could you show me a little examble pls?

Comment: figure out what server sided language you are going to use and look for tutorials on that.   Its the best place to start.  grab the auth code out of one of these https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java